# Can Adobe Target be integrated with Contentful somehow?

Tags: testing, adobe, analytics, contentful

Contentful only suggest Optimizely, but this is not an option for us.

[Contentful - AB tests with Optimizely](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/optimizely-tutorial/)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Adobe Target with Contentful. You will have to create an app for Adobe Target with [App Framework](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/extensibility/app-framework/tutorial/) to integrate it with Contentful since there is no app available in the [Marketplace](https://www.contentful.com/marketplace/).